# how to fetch records from two different tables with no unique fields

Tags: mysql

i have two different tables like table1 and table2. There is no relationship between them.

now i want to retrieve two different fields like field1 from table1 and field2 from table2 using a single query .

select field1,group_concat(field2) from table1,table2. when i use this query data successfully comes if the 2nd table has rows, otherwise all data are null

Comment: It's called a `cross join`, but sample data and expected results would make it easier to understand your question.

Comment: the first table has one row , but 2nd table has multiple rows . i used this query.

Comment: select field1,group_concat(field2) from table1,table2. when i use this query    data successfully comes if the 2nd table has rows, otherwise all data are null

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to use a cross join. Beware that this will result in lots of duplicate data though.

For example, if the tables have the following data:

```
Table 1
Field 1
1
2
3

Table2
Field 2
A
B
C
```

The cross join (eg `select table1.field1, table2.field2 from table1 cross join table2`) will return:

```
Field 1, Field 2
1, A
2, A
3, A
1, B
2, B
3, B
1, C
2, C
3, C
```

As each table has three rows, the cross join returns 3 x 3 = 9 rows. If your tables have, for example, 100 rows each, the query will return 100 x 100 = 10,000 rows. As you can see, the amount of data returned can quickly get out of hand with a cross join.

Since there is no relationship between the two tables, you are likely better off with two queries.

Comment: Looking at your update, the problem is that you are using an inner join (the "," is a shorthand notation for inner join). You need to change it to select table1.field1, table2.field2 from table1 cross join table2).

Comment: Not working sir, this is sample query SELECT school.opening_date,group_concat(holidays.holiday_day order by holidays.holiday_day )as holiday_day from school cross join holidays where school.school_name='ABC'

Answer (score 0):

SELECT tableA.row1,tableA.row2,tableB.row1, tableB.row2
FROM tableA
CROSS JOIN tableB;

Comment: should be columns not rows

Comment: pls see my question , i made changes

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is exactly there in the data. If both the fields are of same type you could take a look at `UNION`. So the overall query will be like

```
(SELECT field1 FROM table1) UNION (SELECT field2 FROM table2);
```

Else if you want a cross product of the two fields (since there is no relationship between them) you could use `JOIN`

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM table1 JOIN table2;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response, pls see my question i added additional info

Comment: What exactly are you aiming for? You could do this `(SELECT school.opening_date FROM school) UNION (SELECT holiday_day FROM holidays)`. So, even if your `holidays` table is empty you can get the school opening date. For the `holiday_day` you will have to just iterate over the result from this query.

Comment: thanks i got, even though result comes as two rows , I can process the data . But is it possible to get as two cols not two rows?